# Buildbot 'try' command starts a build but does not actually apply patch

Tags: buildbot

When I attempt a buildbot try command, the patch is sent and the build starts, but the patch is never actually applied.

My setup uses SVN, with 2 source control steps:

```
c['change_source'].append(SVNPoller("%s/trunk/a" % base_url , pollinterval=10))
c['change_source'].append(SVNPoller("%s/trunk/b" % base_url , pollinterval=10))
```

and...

```
self.addStep(SVN(repourl="%s/trunk/a" % base_url, workdir="build/a"))
self.addStep(SVN(repourl="%s/trunk/b" % base_url, workdir="build/b"))
```

These get put into the build directory on the slave like:

```
build/a/...
build/b/...
```

Then I attempt to run the 'try' command from my local computer:

```
svn co '.../trunk/a'
cd a
update some files
buildbot try --vc svn --connect pb -m192.168.0.100:5555 \
-uuser --passwd=pass -w user -C "comment" --topdir="a"
```

I can see on the server that the patch is generated:

```
svn update ( 11 secs )
patch
stdio
svn_1 update ( 3 secs )
patch
stdio
```

and the patch looks correct-ish

```
Index: mmfx/project/se_lib_tests/mmif_unit_tests.c
===================================================================
--- mmfx/project/se_lib_tests/mmif_unit_tests.c (revision 5952)
+++ mmfx/project/se_lib_tests/mmif_unit_tests.c (working copy)
...
```

However, the patch is never actually applied to the source files.  My suspicion is that buildbot doesn't know how to apply the patch to just the 'build/a' tree -- it attempts to do it to the 'build' tree, and silently fails.

Any ideas how to make this work right?

Thanks,
 - Caleb

Comment: Okay, first problem solved:  My buildbot version was older, 0.8.9.  I updated to 0.8.12, and now the patch is at least applied.  However, now I have a second problem:  the patch, intended for 'a' is applied at each SVN step, and it simply will not apply to 'b'.

Comment: And, I found the other problem:  it seems that the answer is -- you can't have multiple SVN steps.  It seems closely related to http://trac.buildbot.net/ticket/1769?version=0.  I want to specify a subdir for the patch but it's not supported.